# Grand total datagridview calculation problem

Tags: vb.net, winforms

When I insert a subtotal in the datagridview the code recalculates the grand total changes

```
Private Sub BtnSum_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnSum.Click
    Dim somme As Double
    For x As Integer = 0 To DgvDevisClent.Rows.Count - 1
        somme += CType(DgvDevisClent.Rows(x).Cells(4).Value, Double)
    Next
    somme = String.Format("{0:##,##0.000}", CDbl(somme.ToString))
    DgvDevisClent.Rows.Insert(DgvDevisClent.CurrentRow.Index + 1, 1)
    DgvDevisClent.CurrentCell = DgvDevisClent.Rows(DgvDevisClent.CurrentRow.Index + 1).Cells(0)
    DgvDevisClent.CurrentRow.Cells(4).Value = somme
    DgvDevisClent.Focus()
End Sub
```

I need your help or your ideas please.

Comment: Please let us know what the problem is you're having. You've told us what is happening without letting us know what the issue is with it. And you haven't asked us specifically for what you need. This is a Q & A site, not a help or ideas site.

Comment: Is the animated image your code?  Or what you are trying to achieve?  Your code is counting every row, including any "sub-total" row.

Comment: The animation is not my code but I posted it for clarification

Comment: Well, look at your loop.  You're counting everything.

Comment: yes my loop. count everything
I'm a beginner in programming and I tried to write the code but didn't succeed

Comment: Don't do calculations on the values displayed in a DataGridView. Instead, do calculations on the underlying datasource that is bound to the DGV.

Answer (score -1):

You should iterate from the start to the current index, instead of the entire grid

```vb
Dim somme As Double
For x = 0 To DgvDevisClent.CurrentRow.Index
    somme += CType(DgvDevisClent.Rows(x).Cells(4).Value, Double)
Next
```

Comment: Could you provide more detail on what the OP is doing wrong and then why your solution solves the problem?

Comment: @Enigmativity OP should iterate from the start to the current index, instead of the entire grid

Comment: Yes, that's almost exactly what you already said in your answer. Could you provide more detail on what the OP is doing wrong and then why your solution solves the problem?

Comment: And please put that in your answer, not as a comment here.

Comment: @Enigmativity not interested in doing that. Downvote / delete as you desire